# Name of the process on the other end of a unix pipe?

Tags: linux, process, pipe, proc

If two processes are connected by a pipe,

```
> cmd1 | cmd2
```

is there any way for `cmd1` to find out the name (or PID) of the process on the other side of the pipe (`cmd2`)?

Also, vice versa, is there any way for `cmd2` to get the name/PID of `cmd1`?

I know that there is `isatty(3)` to check if the output goes to (or the input comes from) a terminal, so I wondered if there is a way to find out a little bit more about the other hand side.

Comment: This would be platform-specific at best; where are you trying to do it?

Comment: I'd be fine with a Linux-specific version.

Comment: In theory there could be more than one process on the other end of the pipe, if `cmd2` forked.

Comment: Although this may be possible, I really doubt that it's a good idea; this question smells like an XY problem.

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed: `cmd1 | (cmd2 & cmd3)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can see the pipe in `/proc/$PID/fd`. The descriptor is a symlink to something like `pipe:[188528098]`. With that information you can search for the other process:

```
$ lsof -n | grep -w 188528098
sleep      1565   hl    1w     FIFO    0,12     0t0  188528098 pipe
sleep      1566   hl    0r     FIFO    0,12     0t0  188528098 pipe
```

Or, if you want to be sure (for automatic processing) that the number is the socket and not part of a file name:

```
$ lsof -n | awk 'NF==9 && $5=="FIFO" && $9=="pipe" && $8==188528098'
```

With `lsof` 4.88 and above, you can also use the `-E` or `+E` flags:

In combination with `-p <pid>`, `-d <descriptor>`, you can get the endpoint information for a specific *descriptor* of a given *pid*.

```
$ sleep 1 | sh -c 'lsof -E -ap "$$" -d 0; exit'
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
sh      27176 chazelas    0r  FIFO   0,10      0t0 2609460 pipe 27175,sleep,1w
```

Above telling us that `fd` 0 of `sh` is a pipe with fd 1 of `sleep` at the other end. If you change `-E` to `+E`, you also get the full information for that fd of `sleep`:

```
$ sleep 1 | sh -c 'lsof +E -ap "$$" -d 0; exit'
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
sleep   27066 chazelas    1w  FIFO   0,10      0t0 2586272 pipe 27067,sh,0r 27068,lsof,0r
sh      27067 chazelas    0r  FIFO   0,10      0t0 2586272 pipe 27066,sleep,1w
```

(see how `lsof` also has the pipe on its stdin)

Comment: One should be prepared for this to fail; e.g. if the process on the other end has changed UIDs and you don't have permission to `lsof` it.