# See to what the output of a process is redirected

Tags: linux, process, file-descriptors

I have a process that should have his output redirected to output.txt. Unfortunatly the output does not go to this file. First i checked if I called it from another directory, but there is no output.txt, besides the one where the output should go. So I checked the output with `sudo tail -f /proc/2027/fd/1` and saw that the process is running just fine and has a valid output. Also i am pretty sure that I am starting the process correct, because it already worked and i did not change anything on that. My question is now where is the output of the process going? I could only find solutions to see the output, like here: [How to view the output of a running process in another bash session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/how-to-view-the-output-of-a-running-process-in-another-bash-session). But i want to see where the output is redirected to.
Just for completeness, here is how i start the process in java:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "variobox.jar");
builder.redirectOutput(new File("out.txt"));
builder.redirectError(new File ("error.txt"));
builder.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close in showing the output of `/proc/$pid/fd/1`.  As you saw, that will show you the output which is sent to stdout.  But to see *whenceforth* standard output is being sent, you simply need to look at the target of that symbolic link:

```
$ sleep 20 & pid=$!
[1] 88972
$ readlink -f /proc/$pid/fd/1
/dev/pty0
$  sleep 20 > /dev/null & pid=$!
[1] 99996
readlink -f /proc/$pid/fd/1
/dev/null
```

If the target of the link is a pipe and you want to find what's at the other end, see [Name of the process on the other end of a unix pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405485/name-of-the-process-on-the-other-end-of-a-unix-pipe). If the target of the link is a socket and you want to find what's at the other end, see [Who's got the other end of this unix socketpair?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16300/whos-got-the-other-end-of-this-unix-socketpair).

However, if you are seeing output other than what is being sent to your `output.txt` file, that seems to indicate that the output you're seeing is *not* in fact output (or more specifically is not standard output).  It may be standard error, which is file descriptor `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Portably, you can use:

```
lsof -ad 1 -p "$pid"
```

To see what's open on fd 1 (stdout) of process of id `$pid`.

If that's open to a pipe or another inter-process communication channel, on Linux, you can add the `-E` option to see what process is at the other end.